# Super_L fails to bind Win key in .ratpoisonrc

Tags: keyboard-layout, ratpoison

Following the example in the [docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Ratpoison#Using_ratpoison)

```
~/.ratpoisonrc

# Setting the escape key to the Windows key
escape Super_L
```

works fine on one machine. On another however it refers to the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. Both are laptops by the same manufacturer. One difference is one has the Win key to the right and Fn to the left while the other has them swapped.

How to use the Win key on the second laptop instead of Fn?

Comment: This has little do with your WM. Assuming your OS is the same the problem is either the keyboard driver in the kernel has the keys swapped and/or you are missing a udev to remapp the keys yourself. In either case you can check what X/the kernel thinks you are pressing with xev/evtest.
Also see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xmodmap and https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Keyboard_input#Identifying_scancodes